# build git commits one at a time in Hudson

Tags: git, hudson

We have a requirement to Build all Git commits one by one on Hudson. And we donot wan to use the post commit hook or the post receive hook.

We configure the Hudson to do polling at some interval, say 5 minutes. But this would mean that the build happens on the latest commit, if more than one commit comes in during that 5 minutes.
Is it possible to configure Hudson to pull only commit at a time and build only the next commit form what was previously build?

We tried to reset the branch as a first step before build to the "next commit" , but Hudson still thinks it is building the latest commit it fetched in all its logs and reporting.

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense. E.g. if you merge a branch, all commits "appear" at once.

Comment: Are you looking for the SCM polling feature explained here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1246662/43662

Answer (score 0):

One way to do something similar, is to use gerrit+jenkins. The gerrit supports changesets, and one changeset is usually one commit. Jenkins plugin for gerrit could be tuned to verify each changeset by building it.

Answer (score 0):

Write a Hudson action which, on detecting a change on the branch, will successively checkout and build each commit between the last tested commit and the new head.